# Server side validation library for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Can anyone please suggest me good server side validation library for kotlin.
Which can perform basic validation like below

1. Checking for spaces and new line in a string
2. Checking the minimum and maximum of character in a string
3. Checking empty string

As I need to use a validation library instead of below code

```
val data.name = "test test"

val nameMaxLimit: Int = 256

if (data.name.contains(" ") || data.name.isNullOrEmpty() || data.name.length > nameMaxLimit) {
    return true
}
```

My project is a Gradle Project, So gradle supported validation library will be blessed

Comment: What is preventing you to use the core library? So what you already posted `data.name.contains(" ") || data.name.isNullOrEmpty() || data.name.length > nameMaxLimit`, but possibly with a regex for whitespace and newlines, so it catches different types of those?

Comment: Can you help me with the regex pattern , which will be used to find if the string has whitespace or newline or string length > 256 or a empty string

Comment: `^[^\s]{1,256}$` will only match strings with length 1-256, that do not contain spaces, tabs (\t) and newlines (\r, \n) and some other whitespace (\f, \v). Regardless of what validation library you decide to go with, it should have the Pattern/Regex support (and so does Kotlin).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **beans validation**. I think it is the best way.

You would need to annotate each field with the rules you want.
Then you would tell the validations to run.

It would return to you an array of violations.

Here an example:

```
import javax.validation.Validator

val violations = validator.validate(data)
    if (violations.isEmpty()) {
        successAction()
    }
```